# How do I clean Ubuntu installation of Viruses / Miners?

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamav

So it appears our VPS is being hacked, I noticed websites running slow so I checked for processes using htop. There are various cpuminers present, getting processor to nearly 100% usage. I think hack came by outdated installation of commonly used CMS. Processes have owner www-data.

Is it possible to get rid of this somehow? Will clamav catch the viruses or do I need to make a clean installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Set up a new VPS and set up the CMS again from scratch.

Especially if you don't know how to clean the system yourself the safest and easiest approach would be to set up a new VPS. If you don't know what you have to look for and how an infection works, it is very easy to miss something when doing the cleanup and then the infection can start again from these left overs. It is very hard to find and remove all traces of an infection from a system. I have done so for some of our customers, it is possible, but it takes time and knowledge.

If you set up a new VPS don't put the old, outdated CMS installation on that new VPS, as it will only take a couple of hours or days to be infected as well. You have to update the CMS to a supported, secure version and clean out any back doors the attackers have planted. Again, if you don't know how to do this, the easiest way might be to install the CMS on the new VPS and copy the contents from the old installation to the new one. Do not copy the whole database or files as both might contain back doors depending on the CMS in question.

If you have a clean, uninfected copy of the CMS you can copy that to the new VPS.

If you have a copy but it is outdated and you want to keep your old content, you can try to compare the copy with the infected installation. `diff -ru copy infected` might help here, but again you need to know what you are looking for.

With or without a copy, you can also try to list all files that were modified in the past month (or longer if the infection happend some while ago) with `find -mtime -30`. This is however not safe, as the attacker might have faked the modification time of files.

If you see some garbled lines in `.php` files this is often a sign for infected files. Something similar to below is a pretty sure sign of an infected file.

```
eval(base64_decode('ZWNobyAiSGVsbG8gTHViV24sIHRoaXMgaXMgaG93IGNvZGUgb2Z0ZW4gbG9va3MgbGlrZSBpZiBhbiBhdHRhY2tlciB3YW50cyB0byBoaWRlIHdoYXQgdGhlIGNvZGUgZG9lcyBmcm9tIHlvdXIgcHJ5aW5nIGV5ZXMuIjs='));
```

Of course you can `grep -r eval .` for those lines but again not all infections necessarily contain `eval`. There are other ways to execute random code, too, and the attacker might have added code that is not obfuscated.

Please be aware that if you go down this road you have to find all places where the attacker manipulated your CMS and clean them up, otherwise the infection may continue.

In your case there might be a middle way, too. Assuming the attacker has not gained `root` privileges (an assumption that of course is not safe, but as the miners run as `www-data` it is possibly true), you can backup and then remove all files belonging to `www-data`. The backup should of course be on a different system and the CMS should not be run from that backup. You should also clear out the crontab of `www-data` (`crontab -e -u www-data`). If only user www-data is infected this should completely remove the infection from your system and you can start installing a new CMS on the VPS. If the infection continues, you should set up a new VPS and do the CMS installation again.

Regarding `clamav`: you can try to run it, but it most probably won't clear out the infection, so your net gain is probably zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation, I really appreciate that. I know how to get rid of infection of CMS, but I am facing infected VPS for the first time in my life. I ran clamav and it found a trojan.cryptominer which it removed, but I was also seeing running php processes draining processor to 100 percent. I shut down apache server and it killed those php processes. Now I will try to clean the websites and see if it helps. If not, I will be forced to reinstall the whole vps.